# Showing an image depending on what option you choose

Tags: javascript

I was following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1S_NhKkvGA) on how to make a text adventure game in javascript, and wanted to re purpose that code into a game of my own, except depending on what option you choose, the image changes. How would I do that? Original code can be found here (https://codepen.io/WebDevSimplified/pen/xoKZbd), but heres the basic gist of the code:

```
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons')

let state = {}

function startGame() {
  state = {}
  showTextNode(1)
}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
  const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
  textElement.innerText = textNode.text
  while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }

  textNode.options.forEach(option => {
    if (showOption(option)) {
      const button = document.createElement('button')
      button.innerText = option.text
      button.classList.add('btn')
      button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
      optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    }
  })
}

function showOption(option) {
  return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}

function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  if (nextTextNodeId <= 0) {
    return startGame()
  }
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'You wake up in a strange place and you see a jar of blue goo near you.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Take the goo',
        setState: { blueGoo: true },
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: 'Leave the goo',
        nextText: 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

My changes are just the text on the buttons and the story text.

Comment: `const image = document.createElement('img'); img.src = option.imageUrl;` or just have a fixed image and change its src to option.imageUrl that you have defined

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the selectOption function:

```
function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText

  switch (nextTextNodeId) {
    case 2:
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2886284/pexels-photo-2886284.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260')";
      break;
  }

  if (nextTextNodeId <= 0) {
    return startGame()
  }
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}
```

Now you just have to add new cases with your preferred image.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get it working myself, could you show an example with several cases?